# Valid CMIS query

Tags: java, alfresco, cmis, apache-chemistry

I work with Alfresco and OpenCMIS and want get folder and documents.

Query:

```
SELECT D.cmis:objectId, F.cmis:objectId 
FROM cmis:folder AS F JOIN cmis:document AS D 
WHERE IN_FOLDER('"+ folderId +"') 
AND cmis:name like '%name%'"
```

but it doesn't work. Please help me write valid query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot query folders and documents with the same CMIS query. You have to split it into two queries.

Comment: please post an example of split is two